# Unable to run the PHP script in html

Tags: php

I have been trying to display contents between a `<li>` tag when my particular condition is satisfied. Initially I am having a $result string in which I am trying to check for a condition. But I suppose I am doing wrong with syntax.
My code:

```
$Result1 =
'<div id="midrow">
 <ul class="rounded-list">
 <li ><strong>Name:</strong> '.$username.'</li>
     htmlspecialchars('<? if($tips_flag == 1){ ?>');
    <li >Competency 6 - Offer concessions: '.round($per_s6, 2).' percent</li>
     htmlspecialchars('<? } ?>)';
 </ul>
 </div>';
```

My these three lines are incorrect I suppose,

```
echo htmlspecialchars('<? if($tips_flag == 1){');
<li >Competency 6 - Offer concessions: '.round($per_s6, 2).' percent</li>
echo htmlspecialchars('<? } ?>)';
```

Help Plz!

Comment: You can't echo in a variable assignment.

Comment: Removed the echo, but still no success

Comment: What are you trying to do with `htmlspecialchars()`? What you have now is just echoing plaintext; it won't be executed as PHP because you're passing it as a string argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after (not sure about the htmlspecialchars though).

```
$html_additional_content = ($tips_flag == 1) ? '<li>Competency 6 - Offer concessions: ' . round($per_s6, 2) . ' percent</li>' : '';
$Result1 =
'<div id="midrow">
 <ul class="rounded-list">
 <li><strong>Name:</strong> '.$username.'</li>' . $html_additional_content .'
 </ul>
 </div>';
```

That first line is a conditional using the ternary operator. Also make sure your variables there are assigned.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things that are wrong syntax wise. I'm not sure what this code is doing but syntax wise this what's wrong:

```
$Result1 =
'<div id="midrow">
 <ul class="rounded-list">
 <li ><strong>Name:</strong> '.$username.'</li> //you need to put a '; here
    echo htmlspecialchars('<? if($tips_flag == 1){'); //why do you have php 
    //opening there? 

  //here you need to do echo '
    <li >Competency 6 - Offer concessions: '.round($per_s6, 2).' percent</li>
  //you need '; here to end the single tick with a semicolon 
    echo htmlspecialchars('<? } ?>)';

 //you need echo ' here again
 </ul>
 </div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't open and close tags (`<?php` and `?>`) in the middle of a concatenated string. You also can't put an `if` block inside either

```
$Result1 =
'<div id="midrow">
 <ul class="rounded-list">
 <li ><strong>Name:</strong> ' . $username . '</li>';
if($tips_flag == 1) {
    $Result1 .='<li >Competency 6 - Offer concessions: '.round($per_s6, 2).' percent</li>';
   } 
 $Result1 .= '</ul>
 </div>';
```